# If a 2019 UA artificer has the Repeating Shot infusion on two hand crossbows, can they use two-weapon fighting?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, unearthed-arcana, two-weapon-fighting, artificer

It's been established that an [2019 UA artificer](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/artificer-returns) infusing Repeating Shot on a hand crossbow does not need a free hand to reload it, as it produces its own ammunition (and the weapon itself is not two-handed).

If one were to infuse two hand crossbows with this infusion, would the artificer, or another person be able to use two-weapon fighting with crossbows?

It's redundant with the Crossbow Expert feat, but still worth asking.

Answer (score 13):

## No, you cannot

The rules for two weapon fighting start like this:

> When you take the Attack action and *attack with a light melee weapon* that you’re holding in one hand

Regardless of the loading property, a hand crossbow isn't a melee weapon so it doesn't qualify for two weapon fighting. As you noted, you can do two attacks with hand crossbows using Crossbow Expert - although, notably you can do the two attacks in that case even holding just one hand crossbow due to the wording of the feat.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the *Repeating Shot* infusion (like all Artificer Infusions) can only be in one item at a time, so for this scenario to even occur, the Artificer would need to receive the second crossbow from another Artificer.

Comment: @Xirema Could you specify where in the 14 page document the rule stating that is? I certainly haven't managed to find it.

Comment: @Someone_Evil: "You can infuse more than one nonmagical object at the end of a long rest; the maximum number of objects appears in the Infused Items column of the Artificer table. You must touch each of the objects, **and each of your infusions can be in only one object at a time.** If you try to exceed your maximum number of infusions, the oldest infusion immediately ends, and then the new infusion applies."  https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#InfuseItem-597298

Answer (score 5):

## No

Unfortunately, [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) still applies only to melee weapons. Ignoring the ammunition property doesn't change the hand crossbow from ranged to melee(emphasis mine).

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light **melee** weapon that you're holding in one hand...